# PowerShell - how to properly embed in Windows Forms project - .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, scripting

I am using a Windows Forms project just to try to test out some ideas in scripting inside an application with PowerShell scripts. I having trouble figuring out what Nuget package to add.

I have tried multiple versions of System.Management.Automation to my project.
https://foxlearn.com/windows-forms/how-to-execute-powershell-script-in-csharp-444.html
the article above doesn't really get into version information.
When I add the Nuget package I don't see Runspace or PowerShell objects.

I am using Winforms under C# / .NET version 4.7.2. Also, which library/package should you use under a .NET 5 console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Winforms under C# / .NET version 4.7.2

Assuming you want the latest available version for that runtime, you'll want to reference the ["PowerShell 5.1 Reference Assemblies" package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

As the name implies, this package is only a shallow metadata reference, and the resulting binaries will have a runtime dependency on Windows PowerShell 5.1 (default version in all currently supported versions of Windows 10).

---

> Also, which library/package should you use under a .NET 5 console app?

In this case, you *will* want to pick the latest compatible version of the `System.Management.Automation`.

---

If you find yourself in a situation where you have to develop shared PowerShell components for both .NET Framework >4.5 *and* .NET 5, you might want to take advantage of the [`PowerShellStandard.Library` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library/) - it's a .NET Standard package that exposes only the parts of the API that's available in both 5.1 (so it works with .NET Framework apps) and 6 (so it also works in .NET Core / .NET 5)

Comment: Thanks great info!! Is guidance also listed anywhere on official Microsoft sites? That somehow I missed doing my research. Thanks again.